# Glob pattern for empty directories

Tags: javascript, electron, glob, electron-builder

I'm using electron-builder to package my application. It uses glob patterns to match files which can be copied to the resources folder along with the packaged app, this is useful for static files. I have some directory structures (which are trees of empty directories) that I'd like to copy.

The problem is that it only copies directories which have files in them. I'd like it to copy empty directories too.

Here's what I have in my config:

```
builderOptions: {
                files: [
                    "**"
                ],
                extraResources: [
                    {
                        from: "src/modules",
                        to: "src/modules",
                        filter: "**"
                    },
                    {
                        from: "src/assets",
                        to: "src/assets",
                        filter: "**"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Comment: have you tried `**/*` ?

Comment: The usual work-around for something like this is to make those directories non-empty. Just create a file in each of them for the purposes of building. Some people put a `README.txt` or `README.md` file in them and document the reason the directory exist